# Why can't I insert data in database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm trying to insert something into a local database, but it doesn't work..

```
    ModelContainer mc;
    public DBController()
    {
        mc = new ModelContainer();

    }

    public void SaveArtikel(string name)
    {
        mc.Connection.Open();
        int id = mc.Produkt.ToList().Last().ID + 1;
        mc.Produkt.AddObject(new Produkt() { ID = id, Name = name });
        mc.SaveChanges();
        mc.Connection.Close();
    }
```

That's how i tryed it. (It's mixed with german words..)
After that i have access on the articel but it isn't in the database..

EDIT:
The db is an .sdf file.

I right clicked on the project and then i pressed on "new item". There i searched for "Local Database" (Compact Server)

Comment: Did you get any exceptions? Does `mc.Produkt` contain any elements.

Comment: No. There're no exceptions, the only thing is that it isn't in the db.

Comment: Can't make the ID column to auto increment?

Comment: Your current code could be improved like Eranga and Jethro said but it should be working.

Comment: No, that doesn't work with a local db file. I tryed it.

Comment: local db.file? What database are you working on?

Comment: It's an .sdf file.
I right clicked on the project and then i pressed on "new item".
There i searched for "Local Database".

Comment: I've done it this way, because i can't use a MSSQL db here. I have to use a "db-file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think it worked all the time..

I published the project to see how it works there. After many tests it looked very good. Even after I restarted the pc the data were in the db.

I don't know why i can't see the data manually.. but that's no problem.

Thanks to all who helped me!

Answer (score 3):

```
using (var mc = new ModelContainer())
{
    int id = mc.Produkt.Max(p=>p.ID) + 1;
    mc.Produkt.AddObject(new Produkt() { ID = id, Name = name });
    mc.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can try something like the above, also note that I changed this line `mc.Produkt.ToList().Last().ID + 1;` the reason being is that what .ToList() does is retrieve all the database records into memory then searches for then next available Id, where the way I did it, only one record is selected.

Comment: Better check if there are any elements in `mc.Produkt` or it will result in exception

Comment: Thanks for the hint! And yes, there are sample datasets in the db.
But it still don't work. Same as before.

Comment: You can check your connection string, maybe you are looking at the wrong db, I know I've done this a few times before. Also make sure you are not hiding any exceptions, take out any try catch within this method so you know if there is an error.

Comment: The Connetion string should be the right one, because reading works.

Comment: If you add a break point to where you create a new Id, run it twice and if that Id gets bigger then you are adding the product to the database.

Comment: Yes, it gets bigger, but when I start the programm new it's the same as before when i started.. but i want to save it permanently

Comment: I've found out something new! The data is saved as long as I press "Show tabledata" in the db-explorer. Even when I shut down VS the data is saved and i can see it in my program, but when I want to see the tabledata manually.. everything is deleted.. or something like that. After that i can't see it in the program longer..

Comment: Whats database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Compact 3.5.
But I think the "problem" is solved, as i mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what might have been happening to you, is that when you use a local `data.mdf` it has a property set to *always make a copy* to your debug bin folder, and so this happens everytime you debug and run your project. If you target the database in your bin folder, you can see when you insert something it is there, but when you run the project again the table is cleared. What you need to do to constantly track your data is to change the property "copy to output directory" on the `database.mdf`  to "copy if newer".